# Cannot modify equations in a Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, equation-editor

I used Word (2011 Mac) to create a revision file a few months ago. The file contained numerous equations created with equation editor. I just opened the file for the first time in months and now word seems to have converted all the equations into images and won't let me edit them anymore.

Comment: Which version of Wors are you using now? Is it a DOC or DOCX file?

Comment: I don’t know about Word on Mac, but on Windows, if you have a document that uses the new Word equation mode (not equation editor, but more advanced) and save it in a format that is compatible with old versions of Word (.doc format, for Word 2003 and earlier), the equations get converted to images. To fix this, one needs to find the document in the new format (.docx).

Answer (score 0):

It may be that, but it also may be that you don't have Microsoft Equation Editor installed. Check your Office installation, make sure you have all the components installed and enabled. This is usually the problem with "typical" installation which lets out many stuff. I always select custom and enable all components to make sure I don't face such problems. If you have the DVD-ROM of Microsoft Office, start the setup and add all the missing components.